# iOS: AVFoundation: Focus Point

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation, autofocus

**Is there a way to obtain focus point at all times after autofocus has finished?**

In Apple's sample code, they use:

```
    - (void)subjectAreaDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification

{

     CGPoint devicePoint = CGPointMake(.5, .5);

     [self focusWithMode:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus exposeWithMode:AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure atDevicePoint:devicePoint monitorSubjectAreaChange:NO];

}
```

Above code works simply on 'Tap to focus'.  Also it forces the camera to focus in the center of the screen.  I want to obtain focus point at all times, right after autofocus has been finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can just read the [`focusPointOfInterest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/focusPointOfInterest) property to get the current focus point:

```
- (void)subjectAreaDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
     CGPoint devicePoint = device.focusPointOfInterest;
}
```